# How to output elements of an ArrayList as elements are being added?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, output

I am making a program that analyzes a set of student marks. The user should be able to type in a grade (for example, 92, 80, or 50) and they should appear in the textArea provided when they press the Add button. I'm using an ArrayList of Integers to add all these marks as elements, and displaying them correctly and in ascending order. When I try to do this, the output simply displays the number I typed in, and replaces this number once I add a new one. If I try to add a number that's smaller, it just keeps the number before. I feel like my logic is all wrong. Here is the code I have so far:

```
private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    Integer grade;
    grade = Integer.parseInt(markInput.getText()); //I convert the String to Integer to be able to add it to the ArrayList
    if (grade >=0 & grade <=100){
        marksListing(); //This calls the method that actually displays the items in the ArrayList
    }
    else {
    errorLabel.setText("Invalid grade. Please enter a number between 0 and 100.");
    }
}                                         
private void marksListing() {
    Integer grade;
    grade = Integer.parseInt(markInput.getText());
    marks.add(grade);
    Collections.sort(marks);
for (Integer mark : marks) {
    markBox.setText(String.valueOf(mark));
}
```

I researched for a long time and couldn't find how to fix this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the numbers listed, one per line? If so, you just need to build up a big string, with the numbers separated by commas, then put that into your text field. See [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

So here's some pseudocode:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
for(...){
    sb.append(mark).append("\n")
}
markBox.setText(sb.toString())
```

Comment: This is working in terms of it replacing the output before, but now it adds the numbers right beside the other like this: 627080. How do I get them all on different lines? I know you mentioned separating them by commas, but what do you mean?

Comment: Well, I was hoping you'd be able to figure that part out on your own :) I've added that detail above.

Comment: Oh! I see. I've never used a StringBuilder before, definitely a handy tool. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the final `for` loop: `setText` sets the complete text of `markBox`, i.e., you are overwriting the last value each time. You need to add the new mark to the text currently in the box, for example

```
markBox.setText(markBox.getText() + String.valueOf(mark));
```

Between the two, you may want to add a separator to your liking. Outside the for loop, the text should be initialized to an empty string before adding the marks.

Comment: This works, but doesn't take into account that the numbers need to stay in sorted order.

Comment: I added `markBox.setText(markBox.getText() + String.valueOf(mark) + "\n");` but now, it repeats it and adds it to what was in the output box before. For example, it goes: **70**, 62, **70**, 50, 62, **70**. It doesn't replace the output before it, and creates a pattern instead.

Comment: @GreenGiant: I saw the line inside the `for` loop where the marks are already given in sorted order. I added a sentence about initializing the box first.

Comment: @Nat: my bad, I forgot to say that the box has to be initialized to an empty string before entering the for loop. I added a sentence.